# Is there a log file generated from python setup.py install?

Tags: installation, python

When I am installing a python module, I use

```
python setup.py install
```

I see all of the output on the command line, but is all of this output saved to a log file somewhere?  I'm asking because I installed a module on our development server without a problem.  I went to install it on our production server and am having issues.  I was hoping to compare logs of the two installs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like with everything else:

```
python setup.py install >& log.txt
```

Or, if you want the messages to be printed to screen AND log.txt, use:

```
somecommand 2>&1 | tee log.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use the '--record logfilename' argument on that command line to force output to a log.

Comment: that dumps a list of files that were installed, but not all the install details.  thanks though.